# Firebird Visual Studio 2015 DDEX

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net, firebird, ddex

I want to use Firebird with Entity Framework / ADO.NET.

To do this, I

1. Installed EntityFramework
2. Installed FirebirdSQL.Data.FirebirdClient
3. Installed EntityFramework.Firebird
4. Installed the Firebird DDEX

Then, when I try to create a new ADO.NET Firebird Data Source entity connection, as soon as I change the value of any field in the create connection dialog, I get a huge error and VS restarts.

If i change no field, and I click Test Connection, it shows "Connection Succeeded". If i click OK it says :

"Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed". But I just installed it !

It does not do that when I use other providers.

Please help !

This is the error that happens when I try to change a field :

```
   UnhandledException
   at FirebirdSql.VisualStudio.DataTools.FbDataConnectionUIControl.SetProperty(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.LocalModalMessageLoop(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog.Show(DataConnectionDialog dialog, IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.HostServices.Environment.ShowDialog(Form form)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Package.DataConnectionDialog.ShowDialog()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Package.DataConnectionDialog.ShowDialog(Boolean connect)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.EntityDataConnectionDialog.ShowDialog()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Gui.WizardPageDbConfig.newDBConnectionButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.LocalModalMessageLoop(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardForm.Start(IWin32Window parent)
   at Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardForm.Start()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.ModelObjectItemWizard.RunStarted(Object automationObject, Dictionary`2 replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, Object[] customParams)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.Wizard.Execute(Object application, Int32 hwndOwner, Object[]& ContextParams, Object[]& CustomParams, wizardResult& retval)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsProject.AddItem(UInt32 itemidLoc, VSADDITEMOPERATION dwAddItemOperation, String pszItemName, UInt32 cFilesToOpen, String[] rgpszFilesToOpen, IntPtr hwndDlgOwner, VSADDRESULT[] pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.WAProject.AddItem(UInt32 itemidLoc, VSADDITEMOPERATION dwAddItemOperation, String pszItemName, UInt32 cFilesToOpen, String[] rgpszFilesToOpen, IntPtr hwndDlgOwner, VSADDRESULT[] pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.WAProject.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsProject.AddItem(UInt32 itemidLoc, VSADDITEMOPERATION dwAddItemOperation, String pszItemName, UInt32 cFilesToOpen, String[] rgpszFilesToOpen, IntPtr hwndDlgOwner, VSADDRESULT[] pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsProject.AddItem(UInt32 itemidLoc, VSADDITEMOPERATION dwAddItemOperation, String pszItemName, UInt32 cFilesToOpen, String[] rgpszFilesToOpen, IntPtr hwndDlgOwner, VSADDRESULT[] pResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.SVsDialogService.AddNewItem(NewProjectDialog npd, VSNEWPROJECTDLGINFO dlgInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.SVsDialogService.InvokeDialog(VSNEWPROJECTDLGINFO dlgInfo, String& bstrLocation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAddProjectItemDlg.AddProjectItemDlg(UInt32 itemidLoc, Guid& rguidProject, IVsProject pProject, UInt32 grfAddFlags, String lpszExpand, String lpszSelect, String& pbstrLocation, String& pbstrFilter, Int32& pfDontShowAgain)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.WAProject.CmdAddNewItem(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommand.Invoke(Object inArg, IntPtr outArg, OLECMDEXECOPT options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommandService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& commandGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdExcept, IntPtr pIn, IntPtr vOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.FlavoredProjectBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.WAProject.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.FlavoredProjectBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchy.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchy.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.HierarchyUtilities.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<ExecHierParentChain>b__1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(Func`1 method, Boolean reportError, Boolean setShellErrorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.HierarchyUtilities.ExecHierParentChain(IVsHierarchyItemManager manager, IVsUIHierarchy lpUIHCmd, IVsUIHierarchy lpUIHCurrent, UInt32 itemidCurrent, Guid& pguidCmdGroupRef, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.PivotNavigatorCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& guidGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdExcept, IntPtr pIn, IntPtr vOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DocumentObjectSite.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDataSource.Invoke(String verb, Object pvaIn, Object& pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Invoke(String verb, Object pvaIn, Object& pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.NativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& lpmsg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.<>c.<PushMessageLoopOnContextMenuTrackingComponent>b__218_1(Object sender, PreTranslateMessageEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.OleComponentSupport.OleComponent.FPreTranslateMessageCore(MSG[] pMsg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.OleComponentSupport.OleComponent.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleComponent.FPreTranslateMessage>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.OleComponentSupport.OleComponent.CallAndReturnOnException(Func`1 method, Int32 retValueOnException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.OleComponentSupport.OleComponent.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG[] pMsg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UInt32 dwComponentID, UInt32 uReason, IntPtr pvLoopData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.PushMessageLoopOnContextMenuTrackingComponent()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchy.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.WAProject.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application.FlavoredProjectBase.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchy.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchy.ExecCommand(UInt32 itemid, Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.HierarchyUtilities.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<ExecHierParentChain>b__1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(Func`1 method, Boolean reportError, Boolean setShellErrorInfo)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.HierarchyUtilities.ExecHierParentChain(IVsHierarchyItemManager manager, IVsUIHierarchy lpUIHCmd, IVsUIHierarchy lpUIHCurrent, UInt32 itemidCurrent, Guid& pguidCmdGroupRef, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.HierarchyItem.HierarchyContextMenuController.ShowContextMenu(IEnumerable`1 items, Point location)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ContextMenuController.ShowContextMenu(IEnumerable`1 items, Point location, Func`2 getController)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ContextMenuController.ShowContextMenu(IEnumerable`1 items, Point location)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.PivotTreeView.OnContextMenuOpening(ContextMenuEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnContextMenuOpeningThunk(Object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.ContentElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.ContentElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.RaiseContextMenuOpeningEvent(IInputElement source, Double x, Double y, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.ProcessMouseUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.OnPostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.DXCore.Threading.SynchronizationManager.IDENativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: I suggest you create a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET

Comment: make sure there are no duplicated firebird .net provider entries in machine.config. This causes issues and crashes: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-560

Comment: Yes I checked that and i have no duplicate :     https://gist.github.com/ludydoo/d0b79c7fc1aa72c6a52e

Comment: Oh I misread. It's machine.config. I did that and it worked. Please put that in an answert I'll upvote x 1000 million.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firebird .net provider setup has an [issue, that it leaves old entries in the machine.config](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-560). Those duplicate entries cause Visual Studio crashes. after each .net provider update, remove the old entry fro the machine.config, until the bug is fixed and the provider does it on its own. Vote for it in the tracker, maybe the developer fixes it sooner.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea on how to solve this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361988/3211143

Comment: sorry, I never designed the DB in the designer first. I only generate the model from a complete database.

Comment: btw, there is a new providir version 4.9. So Remote the 4.8.1 entry after update or you get the issue again.